# How to add new constraint in XCode 11.5

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints, ios-autolayout

After updating to XCode 11.5, add new constraint options that do not show any options in Storyboard. Any solution for this issue?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first screen shot, you have not selected any subview, so there are no options to add constraints.